# Taking the final value back in recursion

Tags: c

So the goal of this function is to read inputs and counts them while adding them to the input in the reverse order.

""read_the_num()"" is a function that reads the inputs and if there is nothing left to read, FAIL is returned.

thus far if the input is,
1
2
3

my function prints out,
6
2
1

What i need it to print out is,
6
5
4

I can only use recursion for this question.
I basically need to understand how i can count the inputs and then print them out in reverse order while adding the total amount of inputs

inputs => 1 2
 should print 4 3 because there are 2 inputs so add 2 and it has to be printed backwards.

```
int counts(int x)
{
    int n = read_the_num();
    if (n != FAIL) {
        int c = counts(x + 1);
        printf("%d\n", c + n);
    }
    else {
        return x;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    counts(0);
}
```

Comment: Is it complete version of code?

Comment: the code can be modified but should be relatively close to the final solution. Im not understand the idea of bring back the final number using recursion

Comment: Do you need to declare the number of inputs beforehand?

Comment: no i cant do that. inputting 1 2 3 must be somehow counted and then each input is printed in reverse order while i add the total amount of inputs to each input

Comment: if 3 2 1 is the input, then the print statements should be  1 +3 , 2 + 3, 3 + 3. This would equal to 4 5 6

Comment: You didn't `return c` after the `printf` so you end up returning 0 at the end of the function. So only the last element is correct, and all the other elements have 0 added to them.

Comment: @user3386109 you're a god